# Script using web.py runs indefinitely and produces no result

Tags: python, web.py

I'm learning python from Learn Python the Hard Way, and am currently on excercise 50 (https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex50.html). When I run the script in PowerShell on Windows, it runs indefinitely and doesn't produce the predicted result (printing "Hello World" in the web browser). I'm using Python 2.7 The command line looks like this:

```
$ python bin/app.py
http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

and the script doesn't terminate.

I'm running this script from the exercise:

```
import web

urls = (
  '/', 'Index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/')

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        greeting = "Hello World"
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Did you actually type in localhost:8000 into the browser?

Comment: As above, put this in a web browser, and let us know what happens when you do?

Answer (score 0):

It's not supposed to terminate. It's running a web server; the exercise wants you to go to the address printed - http://0.0.0.0:8080/ - in your web browser, where you will see the message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to terminate the local server press ctr+c or ctrl+z in the powershell